# Access VBA Macro Stuck after Few Iterations

Tags: vba, ms-access, import-from-excel

I'm using the code below to

1. load *Microsoft Excel* files into a table (`ChildOne`)
2. aggregate the data
3. insert results into another table (`FinalTable`)
4. drop the previously loaded data
5. call [CompactDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/dbengine-compactdatabase-method-dao?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361) to drop temp data (to bypass the 2GB limitation).

The code gets stuck after few iterations but works fine when executed line-by-line. Please provide any suggestions if there is a way to tune my code for better performance. Thanks in advance!

```
For Each File In FileList
    
    If FileList(i) <> "" Then
        Set AccApp = New Access.Application
        With AccApp
            .OpenCurrentDatabase dbPath
            .DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Child1Append", "ChildOne", FPath + "\" + FileList(i), True
            Sleep 1000
            If i = 1 Then
                .DoCmd.RunSQL ("Delete * from FinalTable")
            End If
            sQuery = "Insert into FinalTable Select distinct '" + FileList(i) + "' as FileName,CompanyID,CalendarYear,CalendarMonthName,sum(AMt) as Revenue from ChildOne group by CompanyID,CalendarYear,CalendarMonthName"
            .DoCmd.RunSQL sQuery
            .DoCmd.RunSQL ("Drop Table ChildOne")
            .CloseCurrentDatabase
            .Quit
        End With
'compacting DB to drop temp memory
        Set AccApp2 = New Access.Application
        AccApp2.DBEngine.CompactDatabase dbPath, dbPathX
        Kill dbPath
        Name dbPathX As dbPath
'Updating the file was loaded successfully on my form
        Status = Status + FileList(i) + " -Successful" + vbCrLf
        MyText.Value = Status
        
        i = i + 1   
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Should not use DISTINCT with GROUP BY. Instead include Filelist(i) in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Ampersand (`&`) character is preferred for string concatenation. Plus (`+`) does work but will have different result when concatenating with Null. Doubt an issue in this case but should be aware.

Answer (score 0):

*First*, you open and close the first instance of Access for every iteration:

```
Set AccApp = New Access.Application
```

Move this outside (before) the loop.

*Second*, having closed Access, you open again an instance of Access:

```
Set AccApp2 = New Access.Application
```

which you *never close*.

Finally, the second Access instance is not needed; one instance of Access can open multiple databases.

So, open one instance of Access before the loop, run the loop opening the databases needed, and then close Access.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Gustav. The reason for closing AccApp object for every iteration was to compact the database in order to shrink the access file size. While the database is open (within the loop) the access wouldn't allow me to compact the database. I tried your approach and it gave me an error - database open to perform compact database.
Thanks for your inputs reg using & instead of + and using the same object for multiple databases. Much appreciated!

Comment: Move the compact to a final step - after the loop.